# Unexpected JavaScript date result

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date

I have the following code to format dates:

```
var currentDate = dateFormat(now, "yyyy-mm-dd"); //dateFormat is a npm package
console.log(currentDate) //returns 2015-12-29
```

My `currentDate` value is saved to a PostgreSQL database. HOWEVER, when I view it, it is `2015-12-29T05:00:00.000Z`. Does anyone know why that additional string is there and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: It's there because that's how Postgres saves it... as a datetime (default) nothing is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the column in Postgres table is of type `timestamp` (with or without time zone).
If you can change it to `date` you will see expected format. 
However, you can always cast the value to type `date`:

```
select '2015-12-29T05:00:00.000Z'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2015-12-29 05:00:00
(1 row)

select '2015-12-29T05:00:00.000Z'::date;
    date    
------------
 2015-12-29
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia,

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a
>   space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC"
>   is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would
>   be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".

Link: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC)

Comment: So is there a way for me to get rid of it?

Comment: I do not understand why you might want to remove it. can you explain a bit more? @downvoter: pray, why?